# Cannot login as new user on MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, permissions, logins, mariadb-10.1

When I create a new user in MariaDB, I cannot login as that user.

First I login to the database as root doing `mariadb` in a bash terminal.

I then run the following commands to create a database and a user:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE mydb;
grant all privileges on mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost' identified by 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

When I then run `SELECT user,host,plugin FROM mysql.user;`, it prints the following:

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| user      | host      | plugin      |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+
| root      | localhost | unix_socket |
| myuser    | localhost |             |
+-----------+-----------+-------------+
```

However, when I then try to login as that user doing `mariadb -u myuser mydb -p`, I have no luck.

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have no idea what is happening.

I am running the following MariaDB version:

```
mysqld  Ver 10.1.44-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 (Ubuntu 18.04)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-p` password prompt seems to be broken. Supplying the password on the command line works as it should.

```
mariadb -u myuser mydb --password="password"
```

Comment: Does your password contain special characters?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille No, it is just a string of alphanumeric characters. I am using a fresh Ubuntu 18.10 installation too, with pretty much only mariadb installed, so there shouldn't be any silly conflicts between programs too. I am lost for words, frankly.

Comment: It's just that I find it hard to believe password entry to be broken.  That would generate a lot of noise.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: Can you try to copy the password, and then "paste" it when you have the password prompt?  In case there would be a problem with the keyboard, or between the keyboard and the chair?   ;-)

Comment: I have tried copy-pasting, using ctrl+v, using shift+insert, and using right click paste.

Answer (score 1):

Try granting to 'myuser'@'127.0.0.1', @'::1', or even @'%'.  In your logs, you will see 'Access denied for user' and what IP address you were trying to connect from.

Comment: I am trying to connect from localhost.

Comment: I believe you, but it is important to find out what mysql sees as your IP.

Comment: I looked into `/var/log/mysql/error.log`, which appears to be the only log file. Never does it mention any failed or successful connection attempts. The final line suggests it's not using an IP at all but rather a UNIX socket: `Version: '10.1.44-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  Ubuntu 18.04`.

Comment: OK, add '-h 127.0.0.1' and '-P 3306' to your connection.

Comment: I ran `mariadb -u myuser -p --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3306`, and it still gave me `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. (still over localhost).

Comment: Can you check if your database is listening on port 3306?  "Never does it mention any failed or successful connection attempts."  Either you don't log warnings, or the database never notices you try to connect.   Try "curl 127.0.0.1:3306".

Comment: I enabled warnings. The error log now has this extra line after a login attempt. `2020-03-30 14:14:59 140048990246656 [Warning] Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. I ran `ss -ta` which tells me there is a socket on `127.0.0.1:mysql`.

Comment: When I check on my mariadb, I don't have a plugin for root. Can you try "UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password', authentication_string = PASSWORD('password') WHERE User = 'myuser';" ?

Comment: I figured out the problem. The `-p` option didn't read the password correctly from the terminal for me. I have to put the password on the command line. I have no idea what causes this and I have never had this happen to me before, but I guess this is a sufficient workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If your password contains special characters, you might want to give **alpha-numeric password** a try. Worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As I commented on the other answer, my password was alphanumeric.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to grant usage for the user, this effectively grants login privileges in MariaDB:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'myuser' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_pwd';
```

Then you can start granting the user privileges to databases:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'my_db'.* TO 'myuser' IDENTIFIED BY 'your_pwd';
```